# What is the purpose of xTaskAbortDelay function in free rtos?

Tags: c, freertos, rtos

I have two task in which i am receving data from bluetooth and if i receive a particular hex value , i want a task(which is Toggling LED State) to run on the basis of the received data.

If there was no data received , then both task should run as per they are scheduled.

I have been trying to use xTaskAbortDelay function , the task does run from the input from bluetooth data, however , after that the LED task is running continously.

Does xTaskAbortDelay creating some problem here?
Should I use something else to achieve the same functionality?

```
TaskHandle_t  lora_send_data_handle;
TaskHandle_t  ble_send_data_handle;
TaskHandle_t  test_data_handle;

static void button_task_check(void * pvParameter)
{
    TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
    const TickType_t xFrequency = 1024;
    xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
    while(1)
    {
        nrf_delay_ms(100);
        SEGGER_RTT_printf(0,"%s","INSIDE SWITCHING\r\n");
        xTaskAbortDelay(test_data_handle);

        vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, (TickType_t) 1024);
    }
}


/*TASK TO RUN LEDS CHECK */
static void led_task_check(void * pvParameter)
{
    TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
    const TickType_t xFrequency = 122880;
    xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();

    while(1)
    {
        SEGGER_RTT_printf(0,"%s","TEST TASK\r\n");
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(RED,1);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(GREEN,1);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(BLUE,1);

        nrf_gpio_pin_write(RED,0);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(GREEN,1);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(BLUE,1);
        nrf_delay_ms(1000);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(RED,1);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(GREEN,0);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(BLUE,1);
        nrf_delay_ms(1000);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(RED,1);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(GREEN,1);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(BLUE,0);
        nrf_delay_ms(1000);

        nrf_gpio_pin_write(RED,0);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(GREEN,0);
        nrf_gpio_pin_write(BLUE,0);
        nrf_delay_ms(1000);

        vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, (TickType_t) 122880);
    }
}


int main(void)
{

    uint8_t rx_qspi[255];
    SEGGER_RTT_printf(0,"%s","reset\r\n");

    nrf_delay_ms(100);

    xQueue1 = xQueueCreate(1, 30);

    ret_code_t err_code;
    err_code = nrf_drv_clock_init();
    SEGGER_RTT_WriteString(0, err_code);

    UNUSED_VARIABLE(xTaskCreate( button_task_check, "t", \            
        configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE + 200, NULL,3,  &lora_send_data_handle));
    UNUSED_VARIABLE(xTaskCreate(led_task_check, "et", \
        configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE + 200, NULL, 2, &test_data_handle));

    vTaskStartScheduler();

    while(1);
}
```

Comment: One problem is that you are not using `vTaskDelayUntil()` correctly.  You are only setting `xLastWakeTime` once outside of the while loops.  But if you want to use `vTaskDelayUntil()` then you should be setting `xLastWakeTime` every loop.  Try using `vTaskDelay()` instead of `vTaskDelayUntil()` and forget about `xLastWakeTime`.

Comment: Another critique is that aborting a delay seems like an awkward inter-task signalling mechanism to me.  Wouldn't a semaphore make more sense?  One task could wait for the semaphore for up to a maximum timeout.  The other task could post the semaphore to signal the first task to run.  I'm unsure though, because it's unclear to me what your actually trying to do.

Comment: It could be interesting to see what happens in `test_data_handle` and why it is being run from `button_task_check` with a `xTaskAbortDelay`. In that case, synchronisation tools such as events or semaphores are much better (although I have no idea what `button_task_check` does).

Comment: Regarding your goal, it is better a semaphore instead of "forcing" a task to run through `xTaskAbortDelay`. `led_task_check` is being executed periodically and when the event or resource is available (in that case, let's consider the resource as the hex value), it will execute the code related to that (blink the LEDs in a different way or whatever). The producer will be the task which is checking the hex value (`button_task_check` ?), and the consumer is `led_task_check`.

Comment: One last comment, think about the use of `nrf_delay_ms`, I don't know if this function is releasing the cpu or not, but it looks like you are not using the advantages of an RTOS (you could create tasks to manage the LEDs, instead of dummy loops from the RTOS point of view).

Comment: @kkrambo I think when we use the Lastupdate time inside the while loop, it executes only one task and after the completion of task  it moves ahead with other tasks(Which totally oppposes the puprose of RTOS which is Running multiple tasks simultaneoulsy) . Correct me if i am wrong !

Comment: From the FreeRTOS documentation: "vTaskDelayUntil() specifies an _absolute_ time at which the task wishes to unblock."  It doesn't make any sense to call `vTaskDelayUntil()` multiple times with the same parameter values.  You're specifying the same absolute time every time.  After the first time `vTaskDelayUntil()` wakes that absolute time is in the past.  And every subsequent call to `vTaskDelayUntil()` that original absolute time is _still in the past_ and `vTaskDealyUntil()` will return immediately, without delay.

Comment: @kkrambo When i print the values of xLastWakeTime , it keeps on incrementing by 122880. Is there something wrong. Will it cause overflow at certain time?

Comment: I'm sorry, my original comment is wrong.  I didn't realize that `xLastWakeTime` gets incremented within `vTaskDelayUntil()` so you don't have to increment it yourself.  But that increment is what you want to avoid specifying the same absolute time repeatedly.  Yes, it will overflow at some point but that is not a problem because the timer counter value returned by `xTaskGetTickCount()` will also overflow at the same time.  In other words the value of `xLastWakeTime` tracks the value returned by `xTaskGetTickCount()` and they will overflow together and continue to track.

Answer (score 0):

Reputation to low to comment. From what you say, everything is working as you said. Need more information:

1. What does the LED task looks like?
2. Do you use preemptive or cooperative scheduler (`#define configUSE_PREEMPTION 1` in freertosconfig.h file).
3. What are the priorities of the three tasks?

Something else to consider is: do you put the task back in BLOCKED state after it has served it's purose? You should check that first. How do you block the task in the first place?

Maybe try using calling `vTaskResume( <LED task handle> )` from the bluetooth tasks and calling `vTaskSuspend()` from the LED task once it has finished it's job. I don't personally think this is the best approach, but it should work.

Comment: I have uploaded the snippet of the code thats causing issue.

Comment: What is your tick frequency? Meaning how much time "122880" is? Is it shorter than 4 seconds (approx running time of LED task)? Because if so.... that would explain it:  `*xLastWakeTime + 122880` is already in the past by the time `vTaskDelayUntil()` is called.

Maybe also print `xTaskGetTickCount()`  alongside TEST TASK: SEGGER_RTT_printf(0,"%s %d","TEST TASK\r\n", xTaskGetTickCount());`. That would reveal if my assumption is correct.

Comment: This value denotes 2 minutes (122880) , 1024 is value for 1 second :)

Comment: What is the definition of TickType_t on your system (size), can it overflow?

Comment: The print value of xTaskGetTickCount is 0 in first run, 122880 in second run and then so on. :)

Comment: The defintion of TickType_t is uint32_t , so i think its big enough

Comment: If i make the value of xLastWakeTime=0 inside the task while loop, it seems to work fine. BUt i doubt that its a better way to do it.

Comment: Are you using preemptive or cooperative scheduler? Because if it is preemptive, then the higher priority button_task_check() will wake up every second, preempt the lower prio led taskr and reactivate the lower priority led_task_check() while it's still running (4 seconds run time).

Comment: I am using preemotive , but i don't know how to use cooperative . Can You guide me to some link on how to use it?

Comment: Sure, find the file named FreeRTOSConfig.h, the first definition there is `#define configUSE_PREEMPTION                    1` set that to 0 and rebuild.

See https://www.freertos.org/a00110.html

Not sure if this is what you want for the rest of your application. I just suggested as a test to check my assumption: the higher priority button_task_check() will wake up _every second_, preempt the lower prio led task and reactivate it (all this before it finished it's job - 4 seconds run time).

Comment: However, non-preemptive means that you won't be "Running multiple tasks simultaneoulsy", but one after the other, therefore it may not be best. For example, button_task_check() won't be able to execute until the led task finishes, meaning button_task_check() will execute at ~4 second intervals only.

Comment: I think its better with the Premptive scheduling then :D

Comment: We have actually dropped the idea of this, because there are other important tasks that need to be run. We did this: We changed the time according to the BLE rxed data. If the LED task was previously blinking after 5 minutes then we made one global variable in which BLE rxed data is stored. If a particular hex value is recived from BLE then we Change the parameter of vTaskDelay() and it is running fine :). 

Not very professonal, but it works